# EXI decoder using OpenEXI in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, decoder, exi, openexi

I cannot find out how to create an EXI decoder using C#/.NET which accepts a MemoryStream containing EXI valid code and simply outputs another MemoryStream containing XML code. I will parse XML code later with custom methods; I'm using EXI only to achieve best compression performances and low memory footprint. Until now, I have found some Java implementations as examples, but none for C#/.NET counterpart; hints of any kind are really appreciated.